# Wrong image dimensions in Insert Media after add_image_size()

Tags: images

I am creating a custom Wordpress theme based on the Bones WP theme. I'm having a problem where an image size that I've specified in functions.php using `add_image_size()` isn't showing the correct `width x height` in the Insert Media dialog.

This is how I add the new image size in functions.php

```
add_image_size( 'portfolio-image-full', 800, 400, true );
```

And using the existing Bones functions, this is how I make this image size appear in the Attachment Display Settings

```
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'bones_custom_image_sizes' );

function bones_custom_image_sizes( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
        'portfolio-image-full' => __('Portfolio large image'),
        'portfolio-image-small' => __('Portfolio small image')

    ) );
}
```

But after uploading an image the 'Portfolio large image' size is 640x320, when it should be 800x400:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Problem solved - the image width was being limited by [`$content_width`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Width) set to `640` in the functions.php file included with Bones WP theme. Hopefully this information will help anyone else struggling with similar problems.

Comment: This way my problems as well, and I'm glad I found this answer! For me `$content_width` was set in my parent theme. I guess it is obvious to most people, but I'll state it anyway: if you are using a child theme it is very easy to just override it by setting `$content_width` to a new value in your child theme functions.php, like this: `$content_width = 1200;`